# Where can I download Tinymce 4.0.28 | tinymce.js File Specifically

Tags: javascript, tinymce, tinymce-4

I have been trying to find ***Tinymce 4.0.28*** js files to run a legacy program I have. The archives I find on github don't seem to have the js file:

**A)**"tinymce.js"
**B)**"tinymce.min.js"

Tinymce Website archive doesn't go back far enough to find the development files either.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: This question is pretty off-topic for SO, but I'll bite. Have you tried taking a look at the github repo [tinymce-dist](https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce-dist/tree/4.0.8)? I think you will find what you are looking for in the tags of that repo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an archive also found here that gives you access to all the older versions: http://archive.tinymce.com/download/older.php

Just download this [[dev]](http://download.moxiecode.com/tinymce/tinymce_4.0.28_dev.zip) version, extract and go to the `js` folder. You'll find what you need there